# Setting unknown property: yii\validators\NumberValidator::0

Tags: yii, yii2

I try to call  a setting form, which shows input forms for saving data into price database.

My model throws the above Exception during rendering:

**Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\validators\NumberValidator::0**

error in line of **_price-item:**

```
$form->field($model, "[{$i}]credits")->textInput(['maxlength' => 8])
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;


use Yii;

/**
 * @package app\models
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $credits
 * @property integer $price
 * @property integer $reduced_price
 * @property integer $discount
 * @property string $start
 * @property string $end
 * @property integer $active

 */
class Price extends \app\base\ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['credits'], 'integer', 'required'],
                [['price'], 'integer','integerOnly' => false,'required', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
                [['reduced_price','discount'],'integer','integerOnly' => false,'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
                [['start','end'],'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],
                [['active'], 'integer'],
                [['active'], 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::$_CONDITIONS)],
                ];
        }
}
```

Widget:

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
            'widgetContainer' => 'wrapper-prices',
            'widgetBody' => '.container-items',
            'widgetItem' => '.item',
            'limit' => 30,
            'min' => 1,
            'insertButton' => '.add-item',
            'deleteButton' => '.remove-item',
            'model' => count($prices) ? $prices[0] : new \app\models\Price(),
            'template' => $this->render('_price-item', [
                'i' => 0,
                'form' => $form,
                'model' => count($prices) ? $prices[0] : new \app\models\Price(),
            ]),
            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
            'formFields' => [
                'credits',
                'price',
                'reduced_price',
                'discount',
                'start',
                'end',
                'active',
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `credits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `reduced_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Can anybody tell me, what is wrong ?
my head almost burns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your first 2 rules

```
[['credits'], 'integer', 'required'],
[['price'], 'integer','integerOnly' => false,'required', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
```

You are setting 2 core validators `integer` , `required` in one rule which is wrong. The [`integer`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator) for example validator takes `max` or `min` parameters and that too as an associative array `'min'=>10`,and assigns the property values like `$obj->min=10`, and your code would force the integer validator to interpret `'required'` as `0=>'required'` , which clearly explains the error above.

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
> Setting unknown property: yii\validators\NumberValidator::0

Chang you rules method to

```
 public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['credits','price'], 'required'],
                [['price'], 'integer','integerOnly' => false, 'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
                [['reduced_price','discount'],'integer','integerOnly' => false,'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
                [['start','end'],'datetime','format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],
                [['active','credits'], 'integer'],
                [['active'], 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::$_CONDITIONS)],
                ];
        }
```

**Update**

Your 4th rule will also be throwing error should be

`[['start','end'],'datetime','format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],`

I have updated the code block above too.

Comment: the error is gone. Now I get
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Invalid validation rule: a rule must specify both attribute names and validator type.

I think I have to read more about configuration rules

Comment: I forgot type datetime for start and end

Comment: its the `date` format in the `[['start','end'],'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],` should be `[['start','end'],'datetime','format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'],` @megadruck

Answer (score 0):

the correct working rule is:

**Thanks to Muhammad**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['credits','price'], 'required'],
        [['price','reduced_price','discount'],'integer','integerOnly' => false,'min' => 0, 'max' => 10000],
        [['start','end'],'datetime','format' => 'php:Y-m-d'],
        [['status','credits'], 'integer'],
        [['status'], 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::$_CONDITIONS)],
    ];
}
```

Comment: i have updated the answer to address the other error too